# Guice throwing OutOfScopeException when executing CompletableFuture

Tags: java, guice, completable-future

From a request scoped thread, `CompletableFuture`s have to be completed by a task running in an executor. The provided Supplier uses a domain specific service `MessageService` which is session scoped. That service is injected by Guice.

```
public class MessageProcessingPage {
    private MessageService messageService;

    @Inject
    public MessagProcessingPage (MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    // Called by request scoped thread.
    public void onProcessMessagesButton () {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        // Called from a thread from the threadpool.
        () -> {return messageService.retrieveMessageMetadataSet(x, y);}
        , executorService);

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

The `MessageService` has a (session scoped) `MessageRestClient` which is injected.

```
@SessionScoped
public class MessageService {
    private MessageRestClient messageRestClient;

    @Inject
    public MessageRestClient (MessageRestClient messageRestClient) {
        this.messageRestClient = messageRestClient;
    }

    public MessageMetaDataSet retrieveMessageMetadataSet(x, y) {
        List<MessageMetaData> listOfMetaData = messageRestClient.retrieve(x, y, z);
        ...
    }

    ...
}

@SessionScoped
public class MessageRestClient {
    ...
}
```

Guice is getting into trouble when it tries to inject the `MessageRestClient`.

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access scoped [MessageRestClient]. Either we are not currently inside an HTTP Servlet request, or you may have forgotten to apply com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter as a servlet filter for this request.
```

I read about a method in `ServletScopes`: [`public static <T> Callable<T> transferRequest(Callable<T> callable)`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.html#transferRequest-java.util.concurrent.Callable-)
But I don't see a way to use this, since no Callables come in to play. Can you help me with a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When processing a servlet request in `Guice`, the `GuiceFilter` has taken care of setting the proper context (via a `ThreadLocal`) so that it can know in which request you are and, therefore, apply the Scopes properly. The instances of the classes annotated with `SessionScope` are actually **proxies** that can access that Request and Session information from Guice and act accordingly.

The task that you have sent to the `CompletableFuture` runs in a separate thread out of `Guice` control. There is no `ThreadLocal` available where `Guice` can get that information from, and, therefore, there is no `Request` nor `Session` information, what means, no `[SessionScope`. As the proxy cannot know anything about the session, it throws the error you are getting.

The [ServletScopes.transferRequest](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/servlet/ServletScopes.html#transferRequest-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) method should inject the needed information so that the scopes work. Should work like this (but never tried):

```
   Callable<MessageMetaDataSet> c = ServletScopes.transferRequest(
               () -> messageService.retrieveMessageMetadataSet(x, y));

   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> c.call()
    , executorService);
```

Comment: Actually would it be worth a new thread, but because the lack of time: I noticed that the use of assisted inject should be avoided in such a scenario. In the `MessageService` I injected a `MessageFactory` (using assisted inject) which is used by a method which is called from a task. Guice got here in trouble too. Since I changed the assisted injected factory with an ordinary factory everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this early: Guice @Inject works all fine:

```
    import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

    public class AsyncFire {

        public static > void execAsync(Class asyncClass) {
            T asyncInstance = AsyncInjector.getInjector().getInstance(asyncClass); //magic
            CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(asyncInstance); //business logic
            completableFuture.exceptionally(asyncInstance); //if error
            completableFuture.thenAccept(asyncInstance); //if success
        }

    }
```

```
    public class ExampleAsync extends Async {

        @Inject //it works
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Inject //it works
        private DAO dao; //your

    }
```

```
    import java.util.function.Consumer;
    import java.util.function.Function;
    import java.util.function.Supplier;

    public abstract class Async implements Supplier, Consumer, Function {
        //...
    }
```

```
    import com.google.inject.Guice;
    import com.google.inject.Injector;
    import com.google.inject.persist.PersistService;

    public final class AsyncInjector {

        private static Injector injector = null; 

        public static Injector getInjector() {
            if (injector == null) {
                synchronized (AsyncInjector.class) {
                    if (injector == null) {
                        injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule()); //your guice module
                        PersistService service = injector.getInstance(PersistService.class);
                        service.start();
                    }
                }
            }
            return injector;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps someone!